Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoPrint', js engine: hermes. React native
I have tried to use the built in pdf generator with 'expo-print' and 'expo-sharing' but even after installing in SDK 51  with the command "npx expo install expo-print" and the other one it's still giving me this error.



import * as Print from 'expo-print';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';

const GeneratePDF = async ({data}) =>{
    const html = `<h1> Teste </h1>`;
    const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html:html,base64:false });
    Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
}

export default GeneratePDF



This is the only thing that I have written and anything that I have tried doesn't work.

create a dev build, npx expo prebuild, and then yarn ios or yarn android

@FaysalB it still gives me the same error nothing new

did you add the expo-print in the app.json plugins?

yes, also I have to mention that I am using an emulator apparently when I run the app on the phone it works.
